# Convert nginx rewrite rules to htaccess/apache rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

i want to move from nginx to apache2. But i cant figure out how to "convert" the nginx rewrite rules to apache/htaccess rewrite rules.

```
    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            if ($uri ~* ^/([a-z]+)$) {
                    set $page_to_view "/index.php?p=$1";
                    rewrite ^/([a-z]+)$ /index.php?p=$1 last;
            }
    }
```

Thank you! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me! In this case i have to say i wasnt very smart at looking this things up by myself...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php\?p=$1 [QSA,L]
```